# How to add items to a StreamController in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to return a list of `members` via a StreamController.

`batches` collection contains batch details and `ids` of `members` assigned to the batch.

So, in-order to get the list of members in a batch, have to loop through `batch` collection and get the `ids` of `members`, then match with `members` collection and return the matching `member` data as `stream`.

```
  final CollectionReference _batchCollectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection('batches');
  final CollectionReference _membersCollectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection('members');

  final StreamController<List<Member>> _membersController =
      StreamController<List<Member>>.broadcast();

  Stream getMembers(String batchId) { //passing a batch id
    _batchCollectionReference
        .document(batchId)
        .snapshots()
        .map((batchSnapshot) => Batch.fromData( //return as Batch type
            data: batchSnapshot.data, batchId: batchSnapshot.documentID))
        .listen((snapshot) {

      List<String> members = snapshot.members; //list of members

      members.forEach((member) {
        var data = _membersCollectionReference
            .document(member)
            .snapshots()
            .map((memberData) => Member.fromData(data: memberData.data)); //return as Member type

        _membersController.add(data);
      });
    });

    return _membersController.stream;
  }
}
```

The problem is I couldn't able to `push` the member data to the `StreamContoller`.

It says,

```
The argument type 'Stream<Member>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Member>'
```

The stream should contains instance of members; Ex: `[[instance of 'Member'], [instance of 'Member'], [instance of 'Member']]`

If I got the data like this way, it would be easy to loop and do the other stuff.

I couldn't able fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you dont need `StreamContoller` (and `Stream.listen()`) at all: just use `Stream` API like `map` / `asyncMAp` / `expand` (or the most generic `transform`) etc

Comment: can you provide any examples? or do you have any video tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstable when you need to add a list to the stream so convert your map data to a list, just adding `toList()` at the end of you map as follows:

```
members.forEach((member) {
        var data = _membersCollectionReference
            .document(member)
            .snapshots()
            .map((memberData) => Member.fromData(data: memberData.data)).toList();
```

And to push the data in the Stream, you need to use `sink.add()` this can be an example of a function to push data into the stream and the other one to get the values:

```
final StreamController<List<Member>> _membersController = StreamController<List<Member>>.broadcast();

  /// Inputs
  Function(List<Member>) get changeMembers => _membersController.sink.add;

  /// Getters
  String get members => _membersController.value;
```

In your case you can do it directly in this way:

```
_membersController.sink.add(data);
```

Hope it helps, for more info please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE) or the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) about streams in dart.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I updated my code as per your suggestion. But now I'm getting this error . `The argument type 'Stream<Member>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Member>'`. What should I do?

Comment: I updated the `StreamController<List<Member>>` to `StreamController<Stream<Member>>` then  it worked. Thanks dude.